# module structure in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

i m moving from simple directory structure to module structure for admin in zend framworks.this is my directory structure

firstproject
   -application
      -config
          -application.ini

```
  -controllers
      -here my controller

  -models
      -here is my model class

  -views
      -here is all views structure

  -modules
      -admin
          -controllers
             -here my controller for admin

          -models
             -here is my model class for admin

          -views
             -here is all views structure for admin

          -bootstrap.php  //bootstrap file for admin

  -bootstrap.php // main bootstrap file
```

my application.ini file is as below

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "modules/default/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH"/modules"
;resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
;resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
;resources.frontController.defaultController = "index"
;resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.modules[] = ""
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "zend"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true


phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[staging : production]
db.params.host     = dev.example.com
db.params.username = devuser
db.params.password = devsecret

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

when i point url localhost/firstproject/admin/user/login its display error like Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)'

i dont know about moduler structure.can anyone help for proper module structure and its redirection...

Comment: This might not seem very helpful, but it is...if you are building something new with Zend, I would use ZF2 not 1.

Comment: Modules are much better separated in ZF2 too

Comment: i want to know for routing to admin panel there is need to change htacesss in zend @ Eddie Jaoude

Comment: You dont need to edit the htaccess!!! I have tried to compare one of my old zf1 projects config with yours, I noticed you have resources.modules[] = "", but I had resources.modules = "". Here is the old project i was referring too (it is a out of date now) https://github.com/eddiejaoude/Zend-Framework--Doctrine-ORM--PHPUnit--Ant--Jenkins-CI--TDD-/blob/master/application/configs/application.ini

Comment: thanx for suggestion..now my project is working fine. i have do it with specified controller name with Admin_indexController in admin module..n its load the request..but i dont know is it right or not which i have done??? @ Eddie Jaoude

Comment: Yes, in ZF1 your controller name must be prepended with the module, i.e. Admin_IndexController